# Raspbian default MQTT Server?

Tags: raspbian, mqtt

As I understand it, Raspbian (`2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full.img`) features Node-Red out of the box.

I have seen the youTube examples that show [Node-Red configuring an MQTT server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQmXWNd1pNk) and left to wonder does the Raspbian image already have an MQTT server?

If a default broker is installed,how does one 'smoke test' the broker?

I would like to understand how to test (from the command line) if an MQTT server is installed, so I can determine if I need to install MQTT on the rPi.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install MQTT, as it is not installed by default.

To check, use `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -l {package_name}
```

for instance, to check if mosquitto is installed, do:

```
dpkg -l mosquitto
```

See also a guide on how to install MQTT on Raspberry Pi [here](https://oneguyoneblog.com/2017/06/20/mosquitto-mqtt-node-red-raspberry-pi/), [here](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/building-distributed-node-red-applications-with-mqtt), and see the tutorial [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-and-node-red-with-mqtt/).

Comment: A good reply.  Q: Is there a comprehensive list of MQTT packages besides mosquitto?

Comment: @gatorback mosquito and mosquito-client, I believe. check documentation to be sure